# WordPress Images not loading after migration

Tags: wordpress, image, migration, hosting, media

I'm facing a problem the last couple of days and I can't figure it out. We changed the hosting company and move our website (same domain name) to another hosting provider. After migration, images not loading, and I can see them broken in WordPress's Media Library.

I tried to change the permissions in the upload folder but that didn't worked. SSL is also working as expected. I disabled all the plugins and even changed the theme, but the problem still persists. I re-uploaded all the backup files again to make sure that I wasn't missing something, but the problem haven't been solved.

I also have the support team from the hosting provider that works on the website, but there's been 2 days now and they can't find a way to solve the issue.

In the browser's Search Console I do see the following errors: https://ibb.co/y0KCmHY

I've also checked the DNS settings in CloudFlare to make sure that I have setup everything correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am no wordpress expert but I think I would first check whether image files in your backup files are not damaged/corrupted.

I would check both your backup files and image files in your new hosting server
(download image files from your new hosting server via FTP)

Sorry I couldn't help you much except where to look at first which you might already know.

Comment: I think all images being corrupted is not a very reasonable explanation. A config mismatch or misplaced images is a more likely scenario.

Comment: I have already checked that and as I mentioned, I did a second migration to make sure that I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the [image](https://ibb.co/y0KCmHY) that you've provided, what I can tell the status is 404 like you know which means your image is not found. Something wrong with all your image URL. You need to make sure the URL is correct for each image you have.

Comment: There are thousands of images uploaded in my client's blog (including the thumbnails). How can I possibly check all the image URLs and what's the possible fix for this? I find it kinda weird because I made so many migrations in the past, but none of them had that problem.